# ¿Cómo crear navegación en tiempo de ejecución y controlar cuando den click en ellos?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Tengo esta función que se encarga de llenar el Navigation View y funciona a las mil maravillas, pero el problema esta en como puedo darle una actividad a cada elemento de Navegación. Gracias de ante mano.

```
private void addItemsRunTime(NavigationView navigationView) {
    //CARGAR MENU DE NAVEGACION
    final Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    bd = new BD(MainActivity.this, "appLuisGonzalez", null, 2);
    SQLiteDatabase db = bd.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] campos = new String[] {"id_categoria", "nombre", "slug"};
    if (db != null){
        Log.e("1","");
        //Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM productos", null);
        Cursor c = db.query("categoria", campos, null, null, null, null, null);
        SubMenu subMenu = null;
        try{
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
                do {
                    int cont = 0;
                    Cursor cursorCategoriaHijos = db.rawQuery(" SELECT id_categoria, nombre, slug FROM categoria_hijos WHERE id_padre='"+c.getString(0)+"' ", null);
                    if (cursorCategoriaHijos.moveToFirst()){
                        do{
                            if (cont == 0)
                                subMenu = menu.addSubMenu(c.getString(1).toUpperCase());
                            subMenu.add(cursorCategoriaHijos.getString(1));
                            cont++;
                        }while (cursorCategoriaHijos.moveToNext());
                    }
                    else{
                        menu.add(c.getString(1));
                    }
                } while(c.moveToNext());
            }
            db.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Error:", "Error al leer datos de la base de datos");
        }
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Error de Conexion a la base de datos local, Vuelva actualizar la Aplicación", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // refreshing navigation drawer adapter
    for (int i = 0, count = navigationView.getChildCount(); i < count; i++) {
        final View child = navigationView.getChildAt(i);
        if (child != null && child instanceof ListView) {
            final ListView menuView = (ListView) child;
            final HeaderViewListAdapter adapter = (HeaderViewListAdapter) menuView.getAdapter();
            final BaseAdapter wrapped = (BaseAdapter) adapter.getWrappedAdapter();
            wrapped.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `SubMenu.add(String nombre)` te devuelve un objeto de tipo `MenuItem` por buena razón. En tu código puedes agregar:

```
        // subMenu.add(cursorCategoriaHijos.getString(1));
        MenuItem mi = subMenu.add(cursorCategoriaHijos.getString(1));
        mi.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                // lo que quieres hacer
                return true;
            }
        }
```